# Set up In-Memory database instance of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'd like to run neo4j 2.3 completely in-memory **as a standalone executable** with a configurable port for test suites. My project's test suites are written *in another language (NOT Java!)*, and will communicate with neo via the HTTP API.

Here is what I've discovered so far:

- The files in the standard build `conf/` directory don't seem to have a way to configure this.
- There is a class [CommunityServerBuilder](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/30a48a04455dc1401b21625914c8113090f5a821/community/server/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/helpers/CommunityServerBuilder.java) that a public `build` method that returns a `TestCommunityNeoServer` server that is pre-configured to be in-memory.

How would I go about using `CommunityServerBuilder` to create and run an in-memory neo4j database? Or is there a config property within `conf/` that will accomplish the same thing?

Comment: did you check the following link that talks about using [ImpermanentDatabase](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html) for unit testing.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I'm not doing unit testing. My test suite is not written in Java.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu the latest versions of neo4j-kernel does not have TestGraphDatabaseFactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a temporary in-memory filesystem (sometimes called a "RAM disk") and [point your neo4j server](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html#_important_server_configuration_parameters) to that (or a "subdirectory") for the DB location.

On Linux, you have several choices for setting up a RAM disk, including `ramfs` and `tmpfs`. [Here is a write-up](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/).

On OSX, there is [a nice script](https://gist.github.com/koshigoe/822455) for mounting a RAM disk. In the Finder, the RAM disk shows up as a device (probably with the name of "untitled") in the Devices list.

On Windows, there are many commercial packages for creating RAM disks, but [this article](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/create-10-gbs-ram-disk-windows/) shows how to use a free tool.

Comment: Assuming you have a path to a RAM disk, how do you point neo4j to use that subdirectory?

Comment: See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html#_important_server_configuration_parameters. The info is right at the beginning. Basically, set the `org.neo4j.server.database.location` value appropriately in your `conf/neo4j-server.properties.` file.

Answer (score 0):

For tests requiring a server instance use `TestServerBuilder` or (when using junit) the test rule `@Neo4jRule`. Both provide a in-process server suitable for testing. See code examples on its usage on http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions-testing.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying to use an in-process server; I mentioned my test suite will communicate with the in-memory neo4j using the HTTP API. Or does this help and I am missing how?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going the custom CE route, how about the Java-based version?

- Download and unzip the java application.
- Use this to create your standard database configuration in a single directory tree

When you need to test,

- Create a RAM disk,
- Copy the standard database configuration to the RAM disk
- Alter the port in the neo4j-server.properties config file

*org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474*

- Start the server
- Conduct your test
- Stop the server / delete the RAM disk