# Is there any Neo4J 3.0 in memory mode

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, in-memory-database

*Is there any way to start Neo4J at in-memory (embedded) mode for heavy computations, not for testing?* I'm speaking not about APOC procedures which load in-memory part of db on demand, but about the way to start everything in memory at once.

*Does Neo4J 3.0 still use Lucene indexes? Is any way to up them in memory?*

Comment: @stdob-- please more details! Do you mean create RAM inside memory? How?

Comment: Something like that: http://www.observium.org/docs/persistent_ramdisk/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36437239/4989460

Comment: stdob-- thank you, I will try! Is there any way to mount as RAM disk existent Neo4J datastore? Will I face any issues?

Comment: No, you must first create a empty ramdisk. Then copy the existing database. The solution must implement saving data in the background from memory to harddisk.

Comment: @stdob-- I have one-time heavy computation with only read queries. I should not persist to hard disk in background, right?  Is APOC warmup https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_warmup better than ramdisk for my needs?

Comment: If you only read operations, so easy - just copy the database to memory disk. About `apoc.warmup` not sure, because it looks like it does not cache properties - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/pull/222

Comment: @stdob-- good point! I haven't seen APOC doesn't copy properties, but I need them. By "just copy the database to memory disk" you mean I can copy db at runtime, when Neo4J server is running?

Comment: No, you need first copy db to memory disk and only after that start Neo4j server.